# how to share data between 2 component angularjs (use typescrip)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-controller, angularjs-components

i have a component :

```
export const TopBarMemberComponent: angular.IComponentOptions = {
        bindings: {},
        require: {
            controller: '^EngagementSetupMember'
        },
        templateUrl: 'topBarMembers.component.html'
    }
```

and parent component:

```
export const EngagementSetupMember: IComponentOptions = {
    controller: EngagementMembersController,
    templateUrl: 'engagement.component.html'
}
```

this is module

```
import {EngagementSetupMember} from './../engagementMembers.component';
import {TopBarMemberComponent} from './topBarMembers.component'

export const topBarMembersModule: string = angular
.module('topbar-members', [])
.component('topbarMemberComponant', TopBarMemberComponent)
.name;
```

but when i use it,screen printed

> can not find EngagementSetupMemberController

please help!

Comment: please provide a bit more code. the module.ts would be interesting, where you assign your components to your module.

Comment: I edited it @scipper

Comment: So, you did not register `EngagementSetupMember`. Adding `.component('engagementSetupMember', EngagementSetupMember)` should do the trick.

Comment: where I should add it

Comment: right above the `topbarMemberComponant` declaration.

Comment: this export an error:
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'EngagementSetupMember', required by directive 'topbarMemberComponant', can't be found!

Comment: Oh yes, did you declare the class `EngagementMembersController` in your `engagementMembers.component.ts`?

Comment: I have declared it as the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look like this so far:

```
// topBarMember.component.ts
export const TopBarMemberComponent: angular.IComponentOptions = {
  bindings: {},
  require: {
    controller: '^EngagementSetupMember'
  },
  templateUrl: requrire('./topBarMembers.component.html')
}


// engagementSetupMember.component.ts
export class EngagementMembersController {}

export const EngagementSetupMember: IComponentOptions = {
  controller: EngagementMembersController,
  templateUrl: require('./engagement.component.html')
}

// module.ts
import {EngagementSetupMember} from './../engagementMembers.component';
import {TopBarMemberComponent} from './topBarMembers.component'

export const topBarMembersModule: string = angular
  .module('topbar-members', [])
  .component('engagementSetupMember', EngagementSetupMember)
  .component('topbarMemberComponant', TopBarMemberComponent)
  .name;
```

Comment: Why use require in templateUrl
if i use it, that will export: Uncaught Error: No topBarMembers.component.html